# identify URL in text view and show in safari iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to identify the URLs/https in my textview and display it in some other color. Also when Click on that it should open in Safari. How can I do that ? Any Sample Application Code available ? I do not want to include Three20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable dataDetectorTypes with your UITextView so URLs (and other common links) are detected and automatically linked to their default application.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
text.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink; // see below for other options
```

See Apple documentation for other dataDetectorTypes options here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1495/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

From iOS7 and later now it becomes more easy to detect link in `UITextView`.

```
UITextView *txtView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 500)];
txtView.delegate=self;
txtView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Implement this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange{

    // do what ever you want
    return YES;
}
```